# Automatically navigate to a new page after a time in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, uwp-navigation

I'm trying to transition/navigate to a new page after a time (let's say 3 seconds), but nothing worked.
I've tried `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage));` and it gives me an error "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*".

I've also tried

```
Thread.Sleep(3000); 
NewPage pg2 = new NewPage();
Window.Current.Content = pg2;
```

but it navigates immediately without waiting the 3 seconds.

The same problem I have also in am Xamarin app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.
In the mean time I've soled my problem and the code I'm using is the following:

```
await Task.Delay(3000);

Frame navigationFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
navigationFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageToNavigateTo));
```

Answer (score 1):

> it gives me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please avoid use `Thread.Sleep(3000)`, it will block UI thread and make Frame as null. And as Silent Programmer mentioned, you could use  [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-20348) to approach.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) };
timer.Start();
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage));
    timer.Stop();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using DispatcherTimer , Dispatcher timer is having tick event, set timer from interval to one second.

write if in timer_tick event and when tickCount hits 3 , navigate to new page

Note : you may required to use coreDispatcher [If exception occures]

hope it help , if not work please comment down